# Draggable events into a FullCalendar

Tags: angular, angular12

I'm using `PrimeNG` and I want to accomplish draggable events into a calendar in Angular, just like in the demo [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging). This is the [live demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo). The problem is that the example is in `Vanilla JS` and angular needs it on typescript.

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rcxzue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fschedule%2Fschedule.component.ts) where I attempted to do so, but the calendar is simply not showing, because of the typescript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that you forgot to add `fullCalendar` directive. Add below code to html:

```
<p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
```

Then in your option add `editable:true`.

Note that you can use `ngModel` to check the checkbox is checked or not but you need to add `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` in your `schedule.module`. I fixed the issue and updated sample link.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xszf5q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fschedule%2Fschedule.component.ts) is working sample.

But I think you also want to drag from other input to `fullCalendar`. So you need to implement draggable event in your service. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069779/unable-to-drag-and-drop-external-events-into-fullcalendar-daygridview) what you want to do second part

Comment: Thank you! Yours work better than yogen darji's (the drag and drop works after you put an item), but "remove after drop" button doesn't work.

Comment: Simply you can add`eventEl.parentNode.removeChild(eventEl)` in eventData function of Draggable,  if yor check box has checked

Comment: I edit my answer to remove tag after dropping. Please check

Comment: Not yet. How do I check if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: you can use `ngModel` directive but seems that you didn't add `FormsModule` in `schedule.Module` and ngModel not working! I fixed it and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `primeng`, you have to add calendar component from primeng like

```
  <p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
```

Now update your `this.options` to accept droppable event.

```
  droppable: true,
```

Also make your events as `Draggable` like below

```
let draggableEl = document.getElementById('external-events');

    new Draggable(draggableEl, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText
        };
      }
    });
```

Full Sample [StackBlitz](https://angular-ivy-ade7m6.stackblitz.io) where I have modified your code

Comment: Thank you! It works but once I put an item on the calendar, I'm not able to drag it from there back to the menu. Also "remove after drop" doesn't work as well.